# Understanding the functionality of the switch in the latent diffusion models: Does conditioning information pass to both cross attention and $z_{T}$?

Tags: papers, diffusion-models

Consider the following diagram from the paper titled **[High-Resolution Image Synthesis with Latent Diffusion Models](https://openaccess.thecvf.com/content/CVPR2022/papers/Rombach_High-Resolution_Image_Synthesis_With_Latent_Diffusion_Models_CVPR_2022_paper.pdf)** by Robin Rombach et. al.,

[image]

In the context of this diagram, I'm uncertain about the functionality of a particular component referred to as the "switch." Based on my understanding, the conditioning information always flows to the denoising step and is directed either to the cross-attention module or to concatenate with $z_{T}$, but not to both simultaneously. Is my understanding correct? Could you explain why the conditioning information cannot be passed to both components at the same time? Is there a specific reason or mechanism described in the paper for this design choice?

Comment: Good question. I also do not understand how the attention output is being used inside the UNET.

Comment: I have only skimmed the paper so far, but my understanding is that you are correct: "not both simultaneously"

Comment: If the convolutional self-attention is implemented as discussed [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/43249/15487), then perhaps the choice is between self-attention and cross attention.  I can see why one couldn't do both.